Difference b/w p4 reconcile & clean commands?
What is the difference b/w  p4 reconcile -n & clean -n commands? i am bit confused on this part.
Both serve same purpose? I am trying to find untracked files on my perforce client.
When i try to run either of the p4 clean OR p4 reconcile it lists the files which are tracked in p4 depot along with untracked files. I am only interested in listing untracked files.
When i try to run either of the p4 clean OR p4 reconcile it lists the files which are tracked in p4 depot along with untracked files. I am only interested in listing untracked files.

Both clean and reconcile find the same files, the difference is what they do with them (if you don't use -n).

If only interested in listing untracked files:
p4 reconcile -a -n

p4 reconcile can detect files what have been added (-a), deleted (-d), or edited (-e).
"p4 reconcile" w/o -ade is equivalent to "p4 reconcile -ade"
p4 clean is just a synonym for p4 reconcile -w.

some reason p4 clean command shows files which are tracked in perforce repository . And those files are shown as :- //sw/test/repo/cube/file.mk - refreshing /home/kept/sw/test/repo/cube/file.mk
Why is p4 clean showing tracked files?
